# Optional Anonymous Parameters Passing in Java

Tags: java, parameter-passing, anonymous-types, optional-parameters

I have two classes A and B. A has a method, say foo, that can have any number of parameters of any types. This method relays these parameters to a method with predetermined number of params of predetermined types.

```
Class A{
   foo(<?> ... params){
      (new B()).bar(params);
   }
} 

Class B{
   bar(int a, int b){
       Log.v("The params passed are "+a+" and "+b);
   }
}

Class Caller{

    callingMethod(){
        (new A()).foo(1, 2);
    }
}
```

I know that the compiler does not allow the signature I have written down for foo; I have written it just to explain what I am trying to achieve.

I dont want to do any casting in the class B's bar(int, int).

Comment: One might argue that if you need such open-ended method parameters in a Java method you might be doing something wrong. The language doesn't really allow for this and in your example, there seems to be no point to such indirection.

Comment: What I am trying to avoid is using a Bundle (/HashMap) in case of which the callingMethod would have to know its content. Also, there would be no restriction on what can be pushed onto the Bundle. This "Bundle approach" is what is used in the lifecycle callback methods of an Activity in Android (savedInstanceState).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested you can accept a variable number of `Object`s as function parameters. The tricky bit is unpacking that to call `bar` on `B`. I've put together an example of how you could do that using reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class test {
  static class A {
    private final Class cl;
    A(Class cl) { 
      this.cl = cl;
    }
    void foo(Object ... params) throws Exception {
      Object obj = cl.newInstance();
      for (Method m : cl.getMethods()) {
        if (m.getName().equals("bar")) {
          try {
            m.invoke(obj, params);
            return;
          }
          catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {} // try next overload
        }
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
  }

  static class B {
    public void bar() {
      System.out.println("Got nothing");
    }

    public void bar(double a, double b) {
      System.out.println("Got doubles");
    }

    public void bar(int a, int b) {
      System.out.println("Got: " + a + " and " + b);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    new A(B.class).foo(1,2);
    new A(B.class).foo();
    new B().bar(1,2);
    new A(B.class).foo("Hello");
  }
}
```

But as you will notice the overload resolution is far from perfect here and passing `1,2` in calls the `double,double` overload of `bar`. To work around that you'd need to sort the array of `Method` objects by best match to the `Class` of each object you are given, but that's far from trivial to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I'm not really in a position to comment on the Android issue, but this at least partly solves the dispatching problem.

Comment: Thanks Flexo ! Really Nice Answer ! Just one thing: why not before calling invoke on m, we call getParameterTypes() or getTypeParameters() and compare the number of parameters the method accepts with the length of params. This would reduce the number of times IllegalArgumentException gets thrown. I wonder if we can use getParameterTypes() or getTypeParameters() to compare the types from params as well. Let me know what you think. Again, though, thanks a lot!

Comment: @SyedFahadSultan That's exactly what you'd want to do to make it more robust, along with checking if the types match. The trouble is that in general terms the rules are quite complicated, for example given a choice between two overloads, one which requires an implicit upcast and one which matches the Object better, but requires an `int`->`long` promotion which gets picked? I don't know the rules off the top of my head, they're at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2 if you want them.

Comment: I'll take a look. P.S. What does a guy gotta do to get an upvote on the question around here? Cause I can't seem to be able to get any :P

Answer (score 2):

You could use variable arguments...

```
public static void foo(Object... parameters ){

}
```

Comment: That doesn't quite answer how to unpack `parameters` to pass them into the new instance of `B`. I'm sort of assuming the OP wants overload resolution to happen still, which is certainly non-trivial.

Comment: But then the callingMethod() would have to know what types to cast the parameters to, which is a problem in my case.

Comment: @SyedFahadSultan - you could do that with reflection, but autoboxing makes that harder. I still think you're probably trying to solve the wrong problem and should step back to look at the design itself and avoid this problem.

Comment: @Flexo I guess you are right. Please refer to my comment above to matt b. I'd be surprised if nobody else has come across the problem I mention in that comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Limited number of parameters which are fixed before varargs.
This is implemented in `EnumSet`

I have changed to `foo` method to accept 3 parameters `E e1, E e2, E... params` which insures that I have minimum 2 parameters to call `bar(e1, e2)` method.

`<E extends Number>` ensures that you can pass any subclass of `Number` `Integer` happens to be one.

```
static class A {
    <E extends Number> void foo(E e1, E e2, E... params) {
        (new B<E>()).bar(e1, e2);
    }
}

static class B<E extends Number> {
    public void bar(E a, E b) {

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    A name = new A();
    name.foo(1, 2, 123);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Varargs in Java:

```
foo(Object... objs) {}
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {}
```

is equivalent to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

Nota: it is equivalent to use an array as long as there are no remaining arguments in the method signature.

Comment: How do you unpack the var args to call `bar` in `B`?

Comment: You'd have to check for params[0] and params[1] being Integers and cast them. It is dirty. But the initial question was about foo's signature to make it compile.

Comment: Sure, but yours doesn't compile `(new B()).bar(objs);` doesn't work.